# eigenvalues distribution

Tags: distributions

How does one plot eigenvalues distribution of a large matrix? I want to plot the distribution to show that the set of eigenvalues of the matrix of current interest is symmetric with respect to the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you need?

```
r = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, 1000}];
ev = Eigenvalues@r;
ListPlot[{Re@#, Im@#} & /@ ev, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300, 
 PlotRange -> 10*{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}]
```

[image]